# dotnet-install: Cannot download sdk Self hosted github runner

Tags: c#, powershell, .net-core, yaml, github-actions

I have self-hosted github runner on my windows vm. It was working fine and suddenly I started getting:

```
dotnet-install: Downloading link: https://dotnetcli.azureedge.net/dotnet/Sdk/3.1.101/dotnet-sdk-3.1.101-win-x64.zip
dotnet-install: Cannot download: https://dotnetcli.azureedge.net/dotnet/Sdk/3.1.101/dotnet-sdk-3.1.101-win-x64.zip
dotnet-install: Downloading legacy link: https://dotnetcli.azureedge.net/dotnet/Sdk/3.1.101/dotnet-dev-win-x64.3.1.101.zip
dotnet-install: Cannot download: https://dotnetcli.azureedge.net/dotnet/Sdk/3.1.101/dotnet-dev-win-x64.3.1.101.zip
Could not find/download: ".NET Core SDK" with version = 3.1.101
Refer to: https://aka.ms/dotnet-os-lifecycle for information on .NET Core support
At C:\Users\Mediapark\actions-runner\_work\_actions\actions\setup-dotnet\v1\externals\install-dotnet.ps1:687 char:5
+     throw "Could not find/download: `"$assetName`" with version = $Sp ...
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (Could not find/...ET Core support:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Could not find/download: ".NET Core SDK" with version = 3.1.101
Refer to: https://aka.ms/dotnet-os-lifecycle for information on .NET Core support
 
Error: The process 'C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe' failed with exit code 1
```

My deploy script:

````
on:
  push:
    branches: [ master ]

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: self-hosted

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - name: Setup .NET Core
      uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v1
      with:
        dotnet-version: 3.1.101
    - name: Install dependencies
      run: dotnet restore
    - name: Build
      run: dotnet build --configuration Release --no-restore
    - name: Test
      run: dotnet test --no-restore --verbosity normal
    - name: Dotnet Publish
      run: dotnet publish -c Release -o deploy```


what could have happened here? It was working fine and now it doesn't?
````

Comment: Checking the download URLs, the binaries are not available where they were hosted.
There are two pathes here, either there is an updated action to setup dotnet, or the sdk version you were using is not available anymore via this action. Alternatively, the SDK is not hosted there anymore and you could open a bug on the action repository [here](https://github.com/actions/setup-dotnet)

Comment: The link didn't work for me either an hour ago, but now it's working again. Maybe try again?